# probability that a five-card poker hand contains a straight flush

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> What is the probability that a five-card poker hand contains a
>   straight flush, that is, five cards of the same suit of consecutive
>   kinds (i.e. <1-2-3-4-5, 2-3-4-5-6, …, 9-10-J-Q-K, 10-J-Q-K-1>?

**My attempt**: We need to chose 5 cards in the same suit, each suit contains 13 different cards so $\binom{13}{5}$, we only need it to be in the same suit so we chose one suit out of 4, that is $\binom{4}{1}$, total number of outcomes is $\binom{52}{5}$, Now there are only 13 situation where we have consecutive kinds, and total number of how we can chose 5 out of 13 regardless of order is $\binom{13}{5}$

Hence, the probability is:
$$\frac{\binom{13}{5}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{5}} \cdot \frac{13}{\binom{13}{5}} = 2.00 \times10^{-5}  $$

However, i think there's something missing or i have made a mistake, can anyone verify my solution ?

Comment: Rather than multiplying by $\binom{13}{5}$ and later dividing by $\binom{13}{5}$, you could have skipped them entirely.  That being said, the number of straight flushes of a particular suit is not considered to be $13$.  "Aces go both ways" is common, but "Aces wrap around" is not.  You have the possibilities $A2345,23456,34567,\dots,10~JQKA$ for a total of *ten* possible choices of numbers for the straights, not $13$.  Usually $KA234$ is not considered a straight.

Comment: It is more common to refer to the card as an Ace rather than as a number 1.  Also, you should never use equals signs for anything except for equality.  Use `\approx` $\approx$ if you are rounding.

Comment: Perhaps see [_this Wikipedia page_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability).